# Does Hilbert–Schmidt theorem imply the space is separable?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

The Hilbert–Schmidt theorem says a self-adjoint compact operator on a Hilbert space have a complete orthonormal set consisting of eigenvectors. Does that imply the space is separable?

Comment: $0$ is a compact operator on any Hilbert space. A Hilbert space $H$ is separable iff there exists exists an injective compact selfadjoint operator $A$ on $H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The eigenvectors are a complete orthonormal set for the *image of the operator.* The space would be separable if the operator were surjective.

Comment: However, compact operators are never surjective.

Comment: They can be surjective iff the space is finite dimensional.

Comment: Thanks! So we can conclude that the orthogonal complement of kernel A is separable?